# PHPUnit: assertInstanceOf() not working when passing type as second argument as non-string

Tags: php, phpunit, assert, assertion

I need to check if a variable is an object of the *User* type.

*User* is my class `$user` my object

```
$this->assertInstanceOf($user, User);
```

This is not working. I have a the following error: `use of undefined constant User - assumed 'User'`.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertinstanceof

I think you are using this function wrong. Try:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('User', $user);
```

As of [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) you can also use:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf(User::class, $user);
```

(From @james2doyle in comments.)

Answer (score 66):

It's always a good idea to use `::class` wherever you can. If you get used to this standard, you don't have to use FQCNs (fully qualified classnames), or escape backslashes. Also, IDEs provide better functionality if they know that `User` here is not just a string, but rather a class.

```
$this->assertInstanceOf(User::class, $user);
```

Comment: I fully agree with this statement, but it sounds more like a comment on the accepted answer than like a separate answer...

Comment: I think this is the required way on PHP Unit 9.5.

Comment: ***Why*** is it a good idea to use `::class`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because it could be a string, as he says

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use something like:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf(get_class($expectedObject), $user);
```

I usually use this when I'm checking i.e. if setter method is returning reference to self.

```
$testedObj = new ObjectToTest();
$this->assertInstanceOf(
    get_class($testedObj),
    $testedObj->setSomething('someValue'),
    'Setter is not returning $this reference'
);
```

Comment: Using PHP 5.6, you could use the `::class` static method, like this:
`$this->assertInstanceOf(ObjectToTest::class, $testedObj->setSomething('someValue')`

Comment: Actually, the `SomeClass::class` feature was added in [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name)

Comment: Yes, of course, but this is not a problem I guess. Services using php version 5.4 and lower are under 10% of total php usages (according to composer stats) https://seld.be/notes/php-versions-stats-2016-1-edition