# Select impossible value in select inputs with Symfony DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I would like to test the behaviour of my application if I send wrong values in a `select` input in form.

This is my form in HTML :

```
<form (...)>
   (...)
<select name="select_input">
     <option value="1">text</option>
</select>

</select>
```

In my test, in get the form with the crawler and try to "select" an incorrect value :

```
$form['select_input'] = 9999999;
$client->submit($form);
/* EDIT */
/*I am expecting the user to not be redirected to the user page,
  and the server to respond with the same form, containing an error message */
$this->assertFalse($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/success_page'));
$this->assertEquals(1, $client->getCrawler()->filter('input.error'));
```

But in the console, I get the message :

```
InvalidArgumentException: Input "user_profile[voteProfile]" cannot take "9999999" as a value (possible values: 1)
```

How can I choose an incorrect value for testing the answer ? It would be possible to send an incorrect value by a real server.

Comment: Did you ever get round solving this issue??? and if you did HOW??? It's been bugging me for a couple of days. -Thanks

Comment: answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28075941/1258172

Comment: I added a simple answer, thanks for reminding my question :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`disableValidation`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Field/ChoiceFormField.html#method_disableValidation) function allow to select impossible values in options :

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('button')->form();
$form->get('select_input')->disableValidation()->setValue(999999);

$client->submit($form);
```

And the job is done !

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says "(possible values: 1)", which matches the one possible value in your form. So, really I think you are getting an exception that you should expect. If a real server were to send an incorrect value, I would suspect this same exception would occur.

In your test, try adding an annotation, like this:

```
/**
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
*/
public function testForm()
{

//test logic here

}
```

Or:

```
public function testForm()
{

$this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgumentException');

}
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683592/phpunit-assert-that-an-exception-was-thrown)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not expecting an Exception from the crawler, but an answer from the server. I edited my post because it was not obvious.