# How to submit an invalid select option in WebTestCase with symfony 2.3

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to test a form in symfony 2.3 that has a select input... along with a file upload (enctype multipart/form-data)

The select input is as follows...

- It is a required field.
- Has 3 options [1, 2, 3]

with the DomCrawler i select the form

`$form = $crawler->selectButton->('Update')->form()`

then try to set the value of the select with

`$form['select'] = null`
or
`$form['select'] = ssjksjkajsdfj`

There is an internal validation system in the DomCrawler that returns the following error if i do that.

`InvalidArgumentException: Input "select" cannot take "ssjksjkajsdfj" as a value (possible values: 1, 2, 3).`

In symfony 2.4 and up there is a magic method in DomCrawler/Form called `disableValidation()` and that works very well. Unfotunately because of some dependencies requiring 2.3 I cannot upgrade

i also tried to use the `$client->Request()` method directly

```
$post_data = '------WebKitFormBoundaryi7fAxO2jrDFTmxef
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="select"

ssjksjkajsdfj
------WebKitFormBoundaryi7fAxO2jrDFTmxef--';

        $client->request(
            'POST',
            $form->getUri(),
            array(),
            array(),
            array(
                'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryi7fAxO2jrDFTmxef',
            ),
            $post_data
        );
```

But symfony does not seem to know/care about the form and just returns a 
regular form without any of the error messages, the form handler doesn't validate the form for some reason.

Here's is the updateAction in the controller

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('CoyoteAdBundle:Ad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Ad entity.');
    }
    $old_entity = $entity;

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        $this->archiveImage($old_entity);

        $entity->upload();
        $em->flush();
        $this->addSuccessFlash('Ad has been updated successfully!');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ad_show', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('CoyoteAdBundle:Ad:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'form'   => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Here i found an exact question... 
[Select impossible value in select inputs with Symfony DomCrawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884366/select-impossible-value-in-tests-in-symfony-crawler)

but the answer is not what i am looking for. I want to test and make sure that the server will return a 200 along with a message letting the user know what they are tying to do is not possible.

PS: I can achieve desired results with Postman in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any method in SF 2.3 that works as `disableValidation`. However, I think sending a fake request should do the trick. I also think the way you're using the request method is not correct. Check the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client) for the 2.3 SF version, you have an example on how to fake a request:

```
// Form submission with a file upload
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

$photo = new UploadedFile(
    '/path/to/photo.jpg',
    'photo.jpg',
    'image/jpeg',
    123
);// Fake photo upload if you like, if not, just send the select value.

$client->request(
    'POST',
    '/submit',// valid route
    array('select' => 'ssjksjkajsdfj'),// Substitute here the name of your select and the value you want to send
    array('photo' => $photo)
);
```

it should send the request and the controller should answer with the 200 and the error if everything's allright.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Ok, a couple of things here: CSRF is important and the format of the parameters in the request too.

Since your form is using CSRF, you should send it along in the request or it will fail and redirect you to the "empty" form. Also, the request must send the data in the proper format. Supposing the generated code of the form names the inputs in the form `my_form[name]` you should create them in the request accordingly:

```
$csrfToken = $client->getContainer()->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('my_form');// Generate CSRF for my_form
        $crawler = $client->request(
                'POST', 
                '/ajax/register', // valid route
                array(
            'my_form' => array(// form accepts params in form my_form[name]
                '_token' => $csrfToken,
                'select' => 'asdfasdf',// select I want to send invalid value
                'photo' => $photo, // the uploaded photo
                'whatever' => 'whatever', // rest of required parameters.
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. i have used that method ... I have no luck getting the error messages from the server... it seems like SF doesn't even care about the form being submitted... just returns the form without any of the errors... as if it was a new request...

Comment: could you post the controller code? Is your form using CSRF validation?

Comment: i updated the question with the controller code.. the form is Using scrf .. but i dont even get the invalid csrf error...

Comment: Great Thanks it worked like a charm... 

its pretty unclear in the SF docs on how to send that array looking form in the fake request...