# testing exceptions with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

i am trying to test a function when i know error i going to be thrown. the function looks like this:

```
function testSetAdsData_dataIsNull(){
    $dataArr = null;
    $fixture = new AdGroup();

        try{
            $fixture->setAdsData($dataArr);
        } catch (Exception $e){
            $this->assertEquals($e->getCode(), 2);
        }

    $this->assertEmpty($fixture->ads);
    $this->assertEmpty($fixture->adIds);
}
```

Now i am trying to use the phpunit exceptions assertions methods to replace the try catch part but i can't figure out how to do that.
i did lots of reading including this post [PHPUnit assert that an exception was thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683592/phpunit-assert-that-an-exception-was-thrown) but i couldnt really understand how it shuold be implemented.

i tried something like this:

```
/**
 * @expectedException dataIsNull

 */

function testSetAdsData_dataIsNull(){
    $dataArr = null;
    $fixture = new AdGroup();

    $this->setExpectedException('dataIsNull');
    $fixture->setAdsData($dataArr);
    $this->assertEmpty($fixture->ads);
    $this->assertEmpty($fixture->adIds);
}

but obviously it didn't work  and i got this error:
1) adGroupTest::testSetAdsData_dataIsNull
ReflectionException: Class dataIsNull does not exist
```

what am i doing wrong and how exactly can i assert if exception was thrown plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use the `@expectedException` annotations for just such cases. See [all exception-related annotations here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException):

```
/**
 * @expectedException \Exception
 * @expectedExceptionCode 2
 */
function testSetAdsData_dataIsNull()
{
    $dataArr = null;
    $fixture = new AdGroup();

    $fixture->setAdsData($dataArr);
}
```

Checking that `$fixture->ads` is really null doesn't really add up here, you can add these asserts prior to the call that actually triggers an exception:

```
$this->assertNull($fixture->ads);
$fixture->setAdsData($dataArr);//throws exception
```

You're *unit* testing. This test serves a clear purpose: it makes sure an exception is thrown in a given situation. If it does, then that's where the test ends.

Still, if you want to keep those `assertEmpty` calls, you could do this:

```
try {
    $fixture->setAdsData($dataArr);
    $e = null;
} cathc (Exception $e) {}
$this->assertEmpty($fixture->ads);
$this->assertEmpty($fixture->adIds);
if (!$e instanceof \Exception) {
    //if the exception is not thát important:
    $this->markTestIncomplete('No Exception thrown');
    //do other stuff here... possibly
    $this->fail('The exception was not thrown');
}
throw $e;//throw exception a bit later
```

An alternative approach would be to call `$this->setExpectedException` manually [as explained here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html). Since we don't seem to know/care what the exception message will look like, I'm going to use the `setExpectedExceptionRegExp` method:

```
$fixture = new AdGroup();
$this->setExpectedExceptionRegExp(
    //exception class, message regex, exception code
    'Exception', '/.*/'. 2
);
$fixture->setAdsData(null);//passing null seems to be what you're doing anyway
```

Comment: thx for the helping @Elias Van Ootegem...so just to make sure, in order to keep executing tests i need to use try catch anyway??

Comment: @DonovenRally: Not at all. If you don't add those `$this->assertEmpty()` calls _after_ the call that throws the exception, the first snippet is all you need. No try-catch anywhere, and the test _should_ be successful